# Notepad++ open dialog weirdness

Tags: notepad++, windows-server-2008-r2

Can some explain the following mystery?
Please refer to https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY5rO.jpg

In the both screenshots, Notepad++ is on the left and Windows Explorer is on the right. Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise is running in VMWare and is accessed via Remote Desktop Connector.

In the top screenshot, notice I am editing

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts   # yes, not in the "etc" sub-directory
```

In the Notepad++ open dialog the "hosts" file is listed.

But the same directory in Windows Explorer shows no such file.

---

In the lower screenshot notice the "etc" directory is not listed in the Notepad++ open dialog, though it is listed in the Windows explorer window. I opened the "hosts" file in Notepad++ by right-clicking the file icon in Windows Explorer and selecting "Edit with Notepad++."

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Better, can someone tell me how to adjust the settings in Notepad++ so it shows the same files as Windows Explorer 2008?

Comment: Wait what? The file is in /etc so I don't really see what it is I am missing here.

Comment: Well for one thing, within NotePad++ I cannot open or save anything in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\ directory because that directory does not exist in the open or save dialog for NotePad++.

Comment: Are you running Notepad++ as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission issue, wherein you only have read/execute perms.  Give yourself write access and see if that changes anything.